How fix "Failed to download repository information"
When updating in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS I get a "Failed to download repository information" message. This problem appeared after some update, as far as I know. I changed nothing. In Software & updates I get te following erro message. 
What is going on - can I fix this. If so how?
Comment: I tried a different server - makes no difference.
